# Rufus scheduler stops on file operations in Nginx passenger

Tags: ruby-on-rails, nginx, cron, passenger, rufus-scheduler

Rails Rufus scheduler perform some file operations. When I start the server, the rufus cron is invoked but the scheduler stops once it encounters file operations

My scheduler looks like below

`deployed_test_scheduler = Rufus::Scheduler.new
deployed_test_scheduler.cron("56 20 * * *") do
  OutputsController.deploy_tests
   puts "Got Deployed Tests"
end`

and the code snippet of deploy_tests methods looks like below

```
....
Rails.logger.info "response0"    
target = open(filepath, 'w')
Rails.logger.info "response1"
target.write(response)
Rails.logger.info "response2"
target.close
Rails.logger.info "response3"
....
```

and production.log looks like below

`.....
I, [2016-12-08T05:03:57.193906 #27950]  INFO -- : response0
.....`

no other logs are printed expect "response0", but works perfectly on WEBrick

What is causing Nginx passenger to stop further processing when it encounters File operations

p.s. rails version -  4.1.6 ruby version - 2.2.0  passenger version - 5.0.30 nginx version -  1.10.1

Comment: Wrap your code in a begin/rescue block and log the error if any.

Comment: One question: is your http://stackoverflow.com/questions/41027855/passenger-behind-nginx-not-preserving-rufus-scheduler-thread solved? It seems so since rufus-scheduler is not killed by Passenger.

Comment: And if you're implying that it's rufus-scheduler fault, you'd better indicate what version of it you are using.

Comment: regarding http://stackoverflow.com/questions/41027855/passenger-behind-nginx-not-preserving-rufus-scheduler-thread The passenger is not serving the application without a UI request. Once client fires the UI, the passenger spawns a new process and keep it active due to "min.instances" property - This ensures the rufus scheduer to get fired.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Seems like your code is encountering a problem and raising an error. Wrap it.

Try with:

```
begin
  Rails.logger.info "filepath is #{filepath}"
  Rails.logger.info "filepath exists? #{File.exist?(filepath)}"
  target = open(filepath, 'w')
  Rails.logger.info "response1"
  target.write(response)
  Rails.logger.info "response2"
  target.close
  Rails.logger.info "response3"
rescue => err
  Rails.logger.error "something went wrong: " + err.inspect
  err.backtrace.each_with_index { |l, i| Rails.logger.error("#{i}: #{l}") }
end
```

It should tell you what filepath you are targetting, if it exists, and what error occurs, if any.

**Addendum**:

If you need an error handler for the whole of the rufus-scheduler instance, you can override its `on_error` handler.

In your case that might look like

```
# ...

deployed_test_scheduler = Rufus::Scheduler.new

def deployed_test_scheduler.on_error(job, error)

  Rails.logger.error(
    "err#{error.object_id} rufus-scheduler intercepted #{error.inspect}" +
    " in job #{job.inspect}")
  error.backtrace.each_with_index do |line, i|
    Rails.logger.error(
      "err#{error.object_id} #{i}: #{line}")
  end
end

# ...
```

See https://github.com/jmettraux/rufus-scheduler#rufusscheduleron_errorjob-error